# Problem Deserialising JSON response from Wikipedia API

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, wikipedia

I am trying to use the Wikipedia search request API thus:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&format=json&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=100&gsrsearch=Simple Harmonic Motion

and then trying to deserialise thus:

```
WikiSearchResults R = s1.Deserialize<WikiSearchResults>(Json);
```

using this class structure:

```
private class WikiSearchQuery{
     public WikiSearchPage[] pages { get; set; }
}

private class WikiSearchPage{
     public int pageid { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }
}

private class WikiSearchResults{
     public WikiSearchQuery[] query { get; set; }
}
```

But I am getting this exception:

No parameterless constructor defined for type of WikiSearchQuery[]

I guess I am misinterpreting the JSON response. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How does json itself look like?

Comment: Add your `Json` data here. Might have problem on your class.

Comment: A Wild Assed Guess says it's because your classes are private. Hence it is not avilable from another namespace/assembly (such as the JSON deserializer). What happens if you redeclare the classes as public?

Comment: Also, the schema does not seem to match the JSON I get from that link.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple issues with deserializing.

As mentioned in the comments by fredrik, your classes are private. Making them public should fix the exception you get.

Additionally, the WikiSearchQuery only exists once and does not contain an array of objects, it does contain a dictionary.

This are the issues I see right now, so this might work:

```
public class WikiSearchQuery{
     public Dictionary<string,WikiSearchPage> pages { get; set; }
}

public class WikiSearchPage{
     public int pageid { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }
}

public class WikiSearchResults{
     public WikiSearchQuery query { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So I tried making the classes public and no change. This is what the JSON looks like:{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "continue": {
    "gsroffset": 100,
    "continue": "gsroffset||"
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "2443": {
        "pageid": 2443,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Acceleration",
        "index": 16
      },
      "19411913": {
        "pageid": 19411913,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Analytical dynamics",
        "index": 90
      },

Comment: Did you also apply the other changes I did next to making the classes public?

Did the error message stay the same?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
        var _reqMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        _reqMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        _reqMessage.RequestUri = new Uri("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&format=json&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=100&gsrsearch=S");

        var response = client.SendAsync(_reqMessage);
        response.Wait();

        var result = response.Result;
        var resultJson = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var tes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WikiSearchResults>(resultJson);
      }
```

Models:

```
public class WikiSearchQuery
{
  [JsonProperty("pages")]
  public Dictionary<object, WikiSearchPage> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class WikiSearchPage
{
  [JsonProperty("pageid")]
  public int Pageid { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("title")]
  public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class WikiSearchResults
{
  [JsonProperty("query")]
  public WikiSearchQuery Query { get; set; }
}
```